# How to trigger an overlay with an image

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of 12 images that show a name and title on hover over each image.
[Grid of 12 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjAWm.jpg)

I'd like to be able to click on each image to show an overlay that will look something like this:
[Overlay triggered by clicking on the top left thumbnail of the previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR5F4.jpg)

It's not happening!

*This is the html I have for that top left image:*

```
<div id="cws_grida" onclick="myFunction"() onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('CWS_GridA','','images/cws_gridaa.jpg',1)"><img src="images/cws_grida.jpg" 
alt="" id="CWS_GridA"></div>
```

*This is the html I have for the overlay (display is set to none):*

```
<div id="cwsOvera">
<p class="cwssub_hdra">Sudha Hajela</p>
<p class="cwssub_bodya">An artist at heart, her love for geometry and color led her into a career as 
an architect and planner...her love for words and imagery leads her to occasionally pen a poem.</p>
<div class="twenty"><img src="images/cws_grida.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

*And this is the script tag I have at the bottom of the body:*

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("cwsOvera");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div with id `cwsOvera` needs to be set to `display:none;`

Then your function should work.

Run the snippet below, I've applied `#cwsOvera {display: none;}` to that div. It will only show after clicking on the image.

***Note**: I've extracted your mouseover and mouseout functions away from the snippet to isolate your problem.*

```js
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("cwsOvera");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

```css
#cwsOvera {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cws_grida" onclick="myFunction();"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/26/11/04/new-years-day-4720210__340.jpg" 
alt="" id="CWS_GridA"></div>

<div id="cwsOvera">
<p class="cwssub_hdra">Sudha Hajela</p>
<p class="cwssub_bodya">An artist at heart, her love for geometry and color led her into a career as 
an architect and planner...her love for words and imagery leads her to occasionally pen a poem.</p>
<div class="twenty"><img src="images/cws_grida.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Additionally, I've updated your function to check if `display === "block"` first. This way the function will trigger on one click instead of two.

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("cwsOvera");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to take a look at my issue, it's very much appreciated. The interesting thing is that only when I made your edit to my div "cws_grida" did the code then run perfectly. I guess it's something to do with an incompatibility with mouseover and mouseout functions?

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Your `div` needed to specify it's style of `display: none` because your conditional logic was checking for it. Without the specification there was nothing for it to check. - As far as your `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions, I excluded them because your question had no code that referred to those functions. There should not be an incompatibility issue with either event.